# How can I get Python scripts to open and execute on Windows 10?

Tags: python

**The Situation:**

I am trying to install and set-up Python 3.9.7 on Windows 10 Pro. However after install I am unable to open any Python Scripts from the Command Prompt, Visual Studio Code, or PyCharm.

**What I have done so far:***

1. Downloaded Python, adding to Path during installation and also removed the Path maximum lenght limit. Python is installed in:

> C:\Users\enriq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\

2. Python is recognized and executed from command promp as follows:

```
C:\Users\enriq>python
```

> Python 3.9.7 (tags/vPython 3.9.7
> (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit
> (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
> more information

3. Tried to open an IDLE executable in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\enriq>Desktop>MyScripts>intro.py
```

> 'Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

4. In Environment Variables:

- Added at the end of System Path the User Path.
- Added at the beginning of User Path, the System Path.
  Both paths are identical now;

> %SystemRoot%\system32 %SystemRoot% %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> C:\Users\enriq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
> C:\Users\enriq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
> C:\Users\enriq\OneDrive\Desktop\MyScripts

5. In Registry Editor:

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment, set the type of the User
> Variable to REG_EXPAND_SZ.

6. Clicked OK after every change, checked there are no spaces after every line in the environment variables. I tried to run the script after every change.

**Additional Information:**

*My machine is:*

> HP laptop recently formatted: processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU
> @ 2.70GHz   2.90 GHz, system type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based
> processor.

**The Question:**

How could I resolve this and get Python to open the scripts?

Comment: Should should not have to write `python intro.py` to execute a python script?

Comment: `C:\Users\enriq>Desktop>MyScripts>intro.py` looks odd :)

Comment: Already have tried different syntax, including "python intro.py" I actually cannot get rid of ">" even I try to use "\" instead. The cmp starts with "C:\Users\enriq>" and if I go backwards, then "C:\Users>" and then "C:\>" whatever I want to input, seems have to go after ">"

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is really a question than an answer but have you associated .py with Python? You can do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're trying to *open* a python script, do you mean you want to *run* the script, or you want to *edit* it? In either case, step 3 is where things are going wrong. To run your script, change your command to something like:

`python C:\Users\enriq\Desktop\MyScripts\intro.py`

If you want to inspect or edit the source code, you should be able to do that via IDLE's graphical user interface. If you already have IDLE open, look for `File > Open` in the menu bar and browse to the location of the file you want to edit.

Outside of using IDLE's user interface to open the file, you could also browse to the `intro.py` file icon in the `MyScripts` folder on your desktop and click to open it. Windows will open the file using whatever application is mapped to `.py` files, and if there is no existing mapping, it should ask you which application you want to use to open the file. You can then choose IDLE, or whichever other editor you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Before lauch my question I tried In the command prompt "python intro.py" and "python C:\Users\enriq\Desktop\MyScripts\intro.py" and other syntax (following tutorials, not ramdomly) with the same result.  Sorry, I should have clarified that before too. The file is already associated with Python...

Comment: When you tried to run your script with `python C:\Users\enriq\Desktop\MyScripts\intro.py`, what *exactly* happened?

I wouldn't expect the same `'Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error - that was because you were passing the path to the script incorrectly.

Comment: The problem is not the syntax when passing the command, as I said, I carefully tried many different ways. The problen might be the windows cmp configuration.

Comment: The `'Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error you saw is because the `Desktop` part of the path you were trying to pass to the python runtime is being interpreted as a command by the Windows shell. Your invocation command is therefore definitely broken.

What exactly happened when you tried `python C:\Users\enriq\Desktop\MyScripts\intro.py`? Please paste the exact command and the error.

Answer (score 0):

To execute. py files you have to invoke python.exe like this:
`python file.py`
or you can execute code with the - c switch:
`python -c "print('hi')"` 
To execute installed modules use the -m switch:
`python -m pip`
I remember that, in the Python installer for Windows, there's also the option to associate. py extension with Python (but personally I don't see the need, since most of the time I use an IDE).
Official docs in case you haven't read them:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Well in terms of windows you can associated file types to bind to an exe file LIKE python.ext or any other executable.

Comment: I have already tried this too. When I start the cmp, I cannot get rid of ">" and I think that is the problem... The file is already associate with Python.

Comment: @Kike That sounds more like a Windows cmd line environment issue (I've seen similar behavior when, in Windows, the path to the file is passed without double quotes). You or some software messed up the path or something. Try resetting the command line and the paths. Then reinstall python. There should be no need to modify the paths or the registry so much after the install.  Also, try: `"full path to python.exe" "full path to file.py"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on you terminal
`C:\Users\enriq>Desktop>MyScripts>python intro.py`
or this
`C:\Users\enriq>Desktop>MyScripts>py intro.py`